# Rails: Sum in 3rd level of nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested, sum

in my rails 3.1 application I have these models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :hours, :through => :tasks  

  def sum_hours
    self.hours.sum(:hours)
  end
end  

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :project  
  has_many :hours 

  def sum_hours
    self.hours.sum(:hours)
  end 
end 

class Hour < ActiveRecord::Base  
  attr_accessible :hours     # column in table

  belongs_to :task  
end
```

in projects_controller.rb this:

```
def show
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  @tasks = @project.tasks.includes(:hours)
end
```

and in projects/show.html.erb I use this:

```
...
<td>Sum hours: <%= @project.sum_hours %></td>
...
<% for task in @tasks do %>
<tr>
  <td><%= task.sum_hours %></td>
</tr>
...
```

But even with *.includes(:hours)* it still uses a query separately for the project and for every task. Am I missing something?? where am I doing mistake???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
@tasks = @project.tasks.joins(:hours).select("tasks.*, sum(hours) as total")
```

Then you can access the sum by,

```
task["total"].to_i
```

I cannot ensure these code works for you. But the basic idea is to join the table and select the sum as an extra field.